# Edit bibitem labels in BibDesk

Tags: bibtex, mac, labels

For those who use BibDesk on OS X, is there a way to add labels to bibitem entries through the UI? A way to put "label" into the BibTeX item like: `\bibitem[label]{key}`?

When items with labels are pulled into BibDesk, it changes the type of citation from, e.g., misc to misc[label] in the pull down menu.

Also, is there another BibTeX editor that can do this? JabRef, etc.?

Comment: Mendeley has a field for this, but on the other hand I don't like Mendeley's bibtex export (as the Mendeley document types don't quite correspond to the bibtex ones).

Answer (score 1):

The interface of BibTex to custom item labels is the `key=` field, which however is only used if no author is given and an alphabetic style is used. As usual,  support within `biblatex` is a lot better:  The `label=` field mimics the `key=` field of classical BibTeX (but also works with numeric styles), whereas the `shorthand=` field provides an interface to explicitly define the label to use no matter what.

To use them with BibDesk just go to *Preferences -> Fields* and add them as new custom BibTeX fields.

I doubt, however, that BibDesk automagically extracts `label` to this fields when pulling `\bibitem[label]` items into BibDesk.